# How do I get the list of windows processes from Google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to get the list of all the applications running in the background using a chrome extension. Is this possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible. Why?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the guides on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in order to better understand your question and provide you with even better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. There is no way to get a list of windows processes from Chrome.

You could use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to run some other process with which you communicate to obtain that information. But, that would not be actually obtaining the information from Chrome. But it would permit you to obtain that information within a Chrome extension.